# Issue with PHP configurations

Tags: php, configuration

I wanted to disable some functions but it seems my modifications don't work.

Under **wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/php.ini** I uncommented the **disable_functions** parameter and added the following values:

```
disable_functions = shell_exec, system
```

When I view **phpinfo();** disable_functions seems unaffected and has no assigned values. I also tried restarting wamp and its services but the result is still the same.

Am I missing something rather obvious?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you restart Apache/PHP?

Comment: For the third time, yes I did.

Comment: Did you get this issue resolved?  If so, what was causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Restart your apache web server.

Linux:

```
service restart apache
```

Windows:

Open Command prompt as Administrator:

```
net stop apacheX.Y

net start apacheX.Y
```

Relace x.y with your version

Comment: @JoshGreenary Are you sure your modifying the correct configuration file, which is loaded when you run `phpinfo()` and have you made sure you saved the changes?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here; maybe try removing the spaces from your declaration like so:

`disable_functions=shell_exec,system`

Let me know if this works, if not I'll keep digging.